# Read a matlab .mat file using h5py

Tags: matlab, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I want to use Python3 package **h5py** to read a matlab .mat file of version 7.3.

It contains a variable in matlab, named *results*.

It contains a 1*1 *cell*, and the value in the *struct* inside is what I need.

In matlab, I can get these data through the following code:

```matlab
load('.mat PATH');
results{1}.res
```

How should I read this data in h5py?
Example .mat file can be obtained from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14G7-e6WuyN-ZBL8bpsX77OT_4cJJFsUp/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `h5py` can read `h5` files from MATLAB, figuring out what is there takes some exploring - looking at `keys` `groups` and `datasets` (and possibly attr).  There's nothing in `scipy` that will help you (`scipy.io.loadmat` is for the old MATLAB mat format).

With the downloaded file:

```
In [61]: f = h5py.File('Downloads/Basketball_ECO_HC.mat','r')
In [62]: f
Out[62]: <HDF5 file "Basketball_ECO_HC.mat" (mode r)>
In [63]: f.keys()
Out[63]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['#refs#', 'results']>
In [65]: f['results']
Out[65]: <HDF5 dataset "results": shape (1, 1), type "|O">
In [66]: arr = f['results'][:]
In [67]: arr
Out[67]: array([[<HDF5 object reference>]], dtype=object)
In [68]: arr.item()
Out[68]: <HDF5 object reference>
```

I'd have to check the `h5py` docs to see if I can check that object reference further.  I'm not familiar with it.

But exploring the other `key`:

```
In [69]: list(f.keys())[0]
Out[69]: '#refs#'
In [70]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]
Out[70]: <HDF5 group "/#refs#" (2 members)>
In [71]: f[list(f.keys())[0]].keys()
Out[71]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['a', 'b']>
In [72]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['a']
Out[72]: <HDF5 dataset "a": shape (2,), type "<u8">
In [73]: _[:]
Out[73]: array([0, 0], dtype=uint64)
In [74]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']
Out[74]: <HDF5 group "/#refs#/b" (7 members)>
In [75]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b'].keys()
Out[75]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['annoBegin', 'fps', 'fps_no_ftr', 'len', 'res', 'startFrame', 'type']>
In [76]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']['fps']
Out[76]: <HDF5 dataset "fps": shape (1, 1), type "<f8">
In [77]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']['fps'][:]
Out[77]: array([[22.36617883]])
```

In the OS shell , I can look at the file with `h5dump`.  From that it looks like the `res` dataset has the most data.  The datasets also have attributes.  That may be a better way of getting an overview, and use that to guide the `h5py` loads.

```
In [80]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']['res'][:]
Out[80]: 
array([[198., 196., 195., ..., 330., 328., 326.],
       [214., 214., 216., ..., 197., 196., 192.],
       [ 34.,  34.,  34., ...,  34.,  34.,  34.],
       [ 81.,  81.,  81., ...,  81.,  80.,  80.]])
In [81]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']['res'][:].shape
Out[81]: (4, 725)
In [82]: f[list(f.keys())[0]]['b']['res'][:].dtype
Out[82]: dtype('<f8')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is asking generally how to read matfiles saved using v7.3 in Python, the [hdf5storage](https://pypi.org/project/hdf5storage/) package provides some utilities that might work for you. In the case of your file (after installing the package) you would run

```
In [0]: import hdf5storage as hdf5
In [1]: pyIn = LoadMatFile('Basketball_ECO_HC.mat')
In [2]: type(pyIn)                                                                                                                                             
Out[2]: dict
In [3]: pyIn.keys()                                                                                                                                             
Out[3]: dict_keys(['results'])
In [4]: type(pyIn['results'])                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray
In [5]: pyIn['results'].shape                                                                                                                                   
Out[5]: (1, 1)
In [6]: pyIn['results'].dtype                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: dtype('O')
In [7]: pyIn['results'][0,0].dtype                                                                                                                              
Out[7]: dtype([('type', '<U4', (1, 1)), ('res', '<f8', (725, 4)), ('fps', '<f8', (1, 1)), ('fps_no_ftr', '<f8', (1, 1)), ('len', '<f8', (1, 1)), ('annoBegin', '<f8', (1, 1)), ('startFrame', '<f8', (1, 1))])
```

You can see it does a good job of parsing the input array, though it does things like collapsing the cell-in-a-cell that you would access in Matlab with `results{1}{1}` into a 2D numpy array you access with `pyIn['results'][0,0]` instead. Another odd thing I ran into with this data is the addition of a dimension in the deeper structure fields, as below:

```
In [8]: pyIn['results'][0,0]['res'].shape                                                                                        
Out[8]: (1, 725, 4)
In [9]: pyIn['results'][0,0]['res'][0,0,:]                                                                                                                      
Out[9]: array([198., 214.,  34.,  81.])
```

Not entirely sure why this happens, but in general it should work well.

That said, I did run into an issue with the latest version (`0.2`) of this package where for really deep array/cell/structure combos it became incredibly slow. The nice thing is that this package is still being maintained, so fixes for this might be in the pipeline. Nevertheless, this prompted me to write my own h5py reader for matfiles which is faster in these cases, and I'll discuss it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my other post on the [hd5fstorage](https://pypi.org/project/hdf5storage/) package, I have run into problems of it being far too slow when it comes to loading deep arrays. So I implemented [my own matfile loader](https://github.com/emiliosalazar/matToPython) whose code might also be more useful (because it's compact) if you care about the specifics of how reading a v7.3 matfile into Python works. (That said, the code currently has very few comments, so maybe not that useful.)

For the case of my library, the outputs are very similar to `hdf5storage`, as shown here.

```
In [0]: from MatFileMethods import LoadMatFile
In [1]: pyIn = LoadMatFile('/Users/emilio/Downloads/Basketball_ECO_HC.mat')
In [2]: type(pyIn)
Out[2]: dict
In [3]: pyIn.keys()
Out[3]: dict_keys(['results'])
In [4]: type(pyIn['results'])
Out[4]: numpy.ndarray
In [5]: pyIn['results'].shape
Out[5]: (1, 1)
```

Note that as with the `hdf5storage` package, the cell-within-a-cell in Matlab, which gets called using `results{1}{1}` becomes a two-dimensional `numpy.ndarray` which gets called with `pyIn['results'][0,0]`, as below.

```
In [6]: type(pyIn['results'][0,0])
Out[6]: dict
In [7]: pyIn['results'][0,0].keys()
Out[7]: dict_keys(['annoBegin', 'fps', 'fps_no_ftr', 'len', 'res', 'startFrame', 'type'])
In [8]: pyIn['results'][0,0]['res'].shape
Out[8]: (725, 4)
In [9]: pyIn['results'][0,0]['res'][0,:]
Out[9]: array([198., 214.,  34.,  81.])
```

In contrast with `hdf5storage`, I opt to make Matlab structures into Python dicts, so that the fields of the structures are the keys of the dictionaries.

In any case, this module is by no means fully tested, but has served me well for loading ~500Mb and larger mat files that version `0.2` of `hdf5storage` doesn't seem to handle (~1.5 minutes for my own loader vs >10 minute loading time for `hdf5storage` (it hadn't finished loading at 10 minutes)). (I'll note that the 1.5 minutes still pales in comparison to Matlab's own <15s load times, so there's still room for improvement...)